# Change group to fan page in Facebook?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-groups

I created a group in Facebook.

Now I want to change it to a fan page and retain the group members as fans.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. From the [Facebook Help pages](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=12811):

> #### I have a Facebook Group. Can it be converted into a Page?
>
> It is currently not possible to convert Facebook groups into Pages. We recommend that you create a Page and notify your group members about it.
>
> Even though there is no limit to the number of people your group can have, you will not be able to send your group a message if it has more than 250 members. If your group has more than 250 members, notify them by posting in the group.